# How do I check if a password in a System.Security.SecureString is empty?

Tags: powershell, read-host

I'm prompting in a script for the user to enter a password for a new account.  I know that using the -AsSecureString parameter causes it to return a System.Security.SecureString object.

```
$AccountPassword = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Password"
```

I just want to check that the password they've entered isn't blank. If I just hit enter at the Password prompt, the tests that I've tried on the $AccountPassword variable are not detecting that it's empty:

```
if (!$AccountPassword) {
  throw "Password must not be empty"
}

if ($AccountPassword = "") {
    throw "Password must not be empty"
}
```

Is there a way to check the System.Security.SecureString variable directly, or do I need to convert it to plain text in order to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Length` property of `System.Security.SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-7.0#properties) class which will *return the number of characters in the current secure string*

Answer (score 1):

Just like a regular `[string]`, `[securestring]` instances have [a `Length` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring.length) reflecting the length of the wrapped string value:

```
if ($AccountPassword.Length -eq 0) {
  throw "Password must not be empty"
}
```